# Is there an online storage service that allows synchronization of public folders?

Tags: cloud, storage, publishing, sharing

What I want is to set up a computer with some application that periodically drops files into a directory which can be made publically available online. Dropbox, for instance, does not allow public sharing of folders (it does allow public sharing of files, which includes a workaround for sharing of all files in a folder) and I don't see if there's even a public folder in Zumodrive or other services. Is there any service that allows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/) might do the job. You would have to manage the directory with Mercurial or Git, but that's not exactly a bad thing.

Comment: still, you have to trigger synchronization after a file changes to push them to the repository, or create a cron job... I was looking for something more automatic, although it's a nice second option.